# Cannot customize log path

Tags: .net, logging, sdk, .net-framework-version, fuslogvw

I created a folder C:\FusionLog and tried to input this in the Log Settings Custom Path field as seen below. However, when I try to put a backslash C:\FusionLog\ I get the following error message below. I tried researching this issue but could not find a resolution.

[Log Path Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tX9Kl.png)

[Log Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjvQ7.png)

Answer (score 0):

That's one of the strange behaviors of the Fusion log viewer, I had that as well.

I was getting tired of using FUSLOGVW.exe so I wrote an assembly binding log viewer named [Fusion++ and put it on GitHub](https://github.com/awaescher/Fusion).

You can get the latest release from [here](https://github.com/awaescher/Fusion/releases) or via chocolatey (`choco install fusionplusplus`).

[image: Fusion++]